# <SwiftUI> Passing references between views when using lists with @Binding

Tags: swift, list, swiftui, view

I'm a newbie in SwiftUI programming and having a basic question.
Wondering why the value in "selectedIndex" in this example is not reflected in the child view, "TestChildView". How can I modify this so that I can get the correct selectedIndex value in the child view?

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {
    @State var selectedIndex: Int = 0
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                List {
                    Section(header:Text("Test")) {
                        ForEach(0 ..< 5, id: \.self) {selectedIndex in
                            NavigationLink {
                                TestChildView(selectedIndex: $selectedIndex)
                            } label: {
                                Text(String(selectedIndex)
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
struct TestChildView: View {
    @Binding var selectedIndex: Int
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(String(selectedIndex))
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the `@State var selectedIndex ...` and the `selectedIndex` in the `ForEach` loop are two different things. That is why it is not reflected in the child view, `TestChildView`.

To `...get the correct selectedIndex value in the child view`, remove the

```
@State var selectedIndex: Int = 0
```

and the `$` in the call of `TestChildView` and use

```
TestChildView(selectedIndex: selectedIndex)
```

Also use `let selectedIndex: Int` in `TestChildView`

EDIT-1:

here is the full test code I use to show it works well for me.

```
 import SwiftUI

 @main
 struct TestApp: App {
     var body: some Scene {
         WindowGroup {
             ContentView()
         }
     }
 }

struct TestView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                List {
                    Section(header:Text("Test")) {
                        ForEach(0..<5, id: \.self) { selectedIndex in
                            NavigationLink {
                                TestChildView(selectedIndex: selectedIndex)
                            } label: {
                                Text(String(selectedIndex))
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TestChildView: View {
    let selectedIndex: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(String(selectedIndex))
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TestView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! I appreciate!
However, it gives following errors.
1. Entry point (_main) undefined. for architecture x86_64
2. Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: updated my answer with the code I used to test my answer. Does this not work for you?